# What does $sin^{-1}x+cos^{-1}y+cos^{-1}xy=π/2$ represent?

Tags: trigonometry

The question asks me to ascertain what $sin^{-1}x+cos^{-1}y+cos^{-1}xy=π/2$ represents. I tried adding them and then trying to simplify the expression, but the expression just keeps getting more and more jumbled and doesn't lead to anything.

Comment: Hint: $$\sin^{-1}(x)+\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$.

Comment: @AMC3F9 Sorry, there was a mistake in the text, the question in the title was correct. I have edited the text to reflect that.

Comment: Try this: Take the 3rd term to the right, use what @AMC3F9 said. Then take sin on both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not getting anything special but this.
$sin^{-1}x + cos^{-1}y + cos^{-1}xy = \pi/2$

So
$cos^{-1}y + cos^{-1}xy = cos^{-1}x$

Using the formula
$cos^{-1}x  - cos^{-1}y = cos^{-1}(xy + \sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$

We get finally

$cos^{-1}xy = cos^{-1}(xy + \sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$
Which on taking cos both sides and solving gives
$x = \pm 1 \space or \space y= \pm 1$
So the equation represents line $x = \pm 1 $ or $y = \pm 1$
On plotting all four lines together you get a square of side length $2$ units.

Comment: This is a square, no?

Comment: Please try putting $x=1$ into the actual equation, it doesn’t satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Soham bro the solution exists in ordered papers as you pointed if you put x =1 then you have to put y=1 then it satisfies.

Comment: So would you get a square anymore?

Comment: Dude but it has not asked for the solution set.it has asked what the expression represents.